# Random Permutation of Characters Java

Tags: java

The code below has to take a string and switch the places of two characters (randomly generated) stringLength() times.

However, sometimes I get two digits more, or two digits less in the output. 
I have tried all sorts of things from changing how I get the randoms to managing the substrings, and I still get these anomalies.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String word = in.next();
for (int wordLength = word.length(); wordLength >= 0; wordLength--){
    int i = (int) (Math.random() * (wordLength - 1));
    int j = 0;
    // j has to be bigger than i.
    while (j < i){
        j = (int) ((Math.random() * wordLength));
    }
    String first = word.substring(0, i);
    String middle = word.substring(i, j);
    String last = word.substring(j);
    word = first + word.charAt(j) + middle + word.charAt(i) + last;
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

The question is from Java for Everyone, but it is specifically NOT homework.

Thanks for your ideas

Comment: From the question you wrote, why not simplify your code by generating two random indexes and swapping the characters at those index for str.length() times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `substring` method is **inclusive** on the lower index. As a result, you are including your swapped characters twice: once when you add them individually and once at the beginning of `middle` and `last`.

You need to start your `middle` and `last` substrings at their respective indices `+1`, to avoid including the characters at `i` and `j` in those strings.

---

You can see what I'm talking about if you put a few `print` lines right *before* you modify `word` (to see what you're about to do). You'll be able to see from these printouts that you're about to repeat some characters.

```
System.out.println(String.format("i: %s, j: %s", i, j));
System.out.println("first: "+first);
System.out.println("char i: "+word.charAt(i));
System.out.println("middle: "+middle);
System.out.println("char j: "+word.charAt(j));
System.out.println("last: "+last);
```

---

As Thomas W pointed out in the comment, you're also going to run into a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsError` when you make this fix, because your loop is inclusive at both the top at the bottom. You'll need to resolve this one way or the other (either at the beginning or the end of the loop) before it'll be fixed completely.

Comment: There's also a bounds error on the outer `wordLength` loop -- it's inclusive on both the top & ending bounds. On the last iteration, `wordLength - 1` will be -1. Not what is wanted.

Comment: Yes, changing the code to `String middle = word.substring(i + 1, j);
   String last = word.substring(j + 1);` did yield a correct result. However I started receiving a String Index Out Of Bounds Error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collections.shuffle(List<?> list)` for permutation. See docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29).

```
String str = "abcdefgh";
Character[] chArr = ArrayUtils.toObject(str.toCharArray());
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(chArr));
System.out.println(ArrayUtils.toString(chArr));
```

Comment: I imagine that would be using Apache Commons Lang for ArrayUtils?